# display:block with pseudo-class not working inside div

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

I was working with pseudo-classes (link, visited, and active) and I have an issue about positioning a link below the others (like a list, I know I can use a list but want to know why is this happening), used display: block but isn't working, the first one works but the second doesn't even though I put display block on all three, here is my codes.

```css
.divlink,
.link:link {
  display: block;
}

.divlink,
.vis:visited {
  display: block;
}

.divlink,
.activ:active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divlink">
  <a class="link" href="https//:youtube.com">Youtube</a>
  <a class="vis" href="https//:google.com">Google</a>
  <a class="activ" href="https//:facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

Here are the screenshots

This is how it looks:
[image: This is how it looks]

And this i how i want to be look like, the only way i can do this is by removing the pseudoclass ":visited" Thanks in advance.e:
[image: And this i how i want to be look like, the only way i can do this is by removing the pseudoclass ":visited" Thanks in advance.e]

Comment: the display property will not propagate to children of `.divlink`.. you should have a better selector like `.divlink > *`

Comment: no please no advise to use universal selector, that so bad in terms of performance

Comment: The second link isn't visited so the rule doesn't apply, and the third one isn't active, so the rule doesn't apply.

Comment: @dippas please let's unite to reject the universal selector alltogether against the w3c! I wish you could understand the difference between trying to show a point and adopting a point blindly with no understanding at all. That selector just stressed to make a rule for direct children .. if you want to make a raccomendation for that selector to be more specific than * there are better ways to state it without blaming because my intention was just "direct children".

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I think a better way would be to use `.divlink > a`  or `.divlink a` you get the same result as the universal `*` selector, but with less performance issues. I understand the point you were trying to make in this simple example.

Comment: @disinfor .. well why not being even more specific?? `div.divlink > a[href='https//:youtube.com'].link, div.divlink > a[href='https//:google.com'].vis, div.divlink > a[href='https//:facebook.com'].activ` now is it ok?? what if you have another element type with that divlink class? didn't you think about it? but of course I perfectly understand your point! of course!

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I think you misunderstand. I'm not saying what you suggested was bad in this simple example. Getting more specific creates other issues in this example. I'm suggesting that `.divlink a` or `.divlink > a` would be a better choice. There is nothing wrong with what you suggested for this simple example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set this code:

```
.divlink a {
display: block;
}
```

just remove all those codes and put this.
this will make the link just like what you've wanted as an output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!! While this does answer the question, you should add more explanation about **why** the code works or what the code is doing. That makes better answers for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are only setting `display:block` to the parent `divlink` and the pseudo classes not the `a`,

you are only getting the first link displayed as block because `:link` is a un-visited link, the other two `:visited` and `:active`, aren't displayed as block because the link in the second rule wasn't visited and in the last one it isn't active

You can set to `a` or a class in `a` because the pseudo classes will inherit from it

```css
.link  {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="divlink">
  <a class="link" href="https://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
  <a class="link vis" href="https://google.com">Google</a>
  <a class="link activ" href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</div>
```